# how to set background mobile from imageView

Tags: android, image, background, imageview

i have One Image View and i want to set as background mobile from image in image View

background mobile = image in imageView

How to do it?

Comment: background mobile? you mean you want to set wallpaper?

Answer (score -1):

Refer android docs:

```
 imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.urView);
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```